# Where else can I go for identification help?

Tags: discussion, support, identification-questions

I seem to be getting booted off the site for asking identification request- type questions. This is problematic as I need these cels identified for my job. Please help me!

Comment: [/r/animesuggest](http://www.reddit.com/r/animesuggest), [MAL](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1404673), [ACDB](https://www.animecharactersdatabase.com/)

Comment: So just to make things clear, we don't have anything against you. The problem is that your questions don't match the spirit of the kinds of questions stack exchange wants on their sites. Stack exchange likes questions that will benefit more than just the person asking the question. One or two questions of such nature can be forgiven, but your questions, all of them, will not benefit anyone other than yourself.

Comment: And really, if I were in your shoes, I would find a list of anime studios and start sending out emails.

Comment: As the two comments right above this one suggest, no one is booting you off of our site. You are not being singled out, and your posts are being judged for their own merits (or lack thereof) and not based on the fact that you're the one posting them. Have a look at [this post](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/2472/49) for a better understanding of what are our current guidelines for this type of question, and how you can possibly improve yours to get some answers.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to the idea that you are using this site to help you do your job, and I don't think there's anything wrong with that, _per se_. We would never tell somebody on Stack Overflow who asks a work-related question to "be professional" and go somewhere else, provided that their questions were good; that's half the point of the site! The fundamental issue here is that the particular _kinds_ of questions you're asking - identification-requests - inherently suck.

Comment: How many cels do you need to identify?

Comment: 127 cels need to be identified.

Comment: yea, you're wasting your effort and time, get a few representative cels, zip them up, type up a form letter, and track down anime studios and ask for help via a bulk email.

Comment: you can probably even just add the links to this site

Answer (score 15):

Firstly I'd like to say that that's an interesting job and I'm jealous.

But to the main point (most of which has been detailed in the comments by other users);

127 cels is a lot of questions. If you're experiencing blocks it's possibly  because the site has rate-limiting enabled. This is basically to ensure that a user is not asking a lot of low-quality questions or spamming.

The fact that these questions aren't getting many upvotes is additional to this effect. The system probably considers users posting consistently good questions to be not doing any harm.

It might be worth reading these posts:

- [The complete Rate Limiting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)
- [Rate limitations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited)

---

You aren't getting many upvotes because the questions have little substance to them and aren't interesting to other users.

Additionally, repeated questions that users aren't fond of tend to acquire downvotes too - and that further leads to blockages and low-visibility of your questions.

This is a community, not a input-output answer box.

---

If I were in your shoes I think the best course of action is to spread your search amongst other sites such as [/r/animesuggest](http://www.reddit.com/r/animesuggest) , [Anime Characters Database](https://www.animecharactersdatabase.com/), Forums and other sites that deal with these questions also.

>100 Questions on the same topic is not going to be looked upon fondly by any one site due to the change in flow of how the sites work.

**TL;DR:** The questions you're asking aren't getting any positive feedback from the users of this site so they're not receiving much attention and because of this you're potentially being rate limited. Two options - Spread your search elsewhere or improve the quality of your questions.

As a side note, If you have an imgur gallery of all the cels - feel free to comment with it below and I can scan through them if you want and see if I recognise any. (Unrelated to the site)

Comment: *This is a community, not a input-output answer box.* - Indeed. Realistically I don't think most people here are prepared to sit down and identify 127 different cels (many of which seem to be quite obscure).

Comment: Even most of our oldest users haven't asked that many *questions*, let alone ID-req's. 127 is completely excessive.

Comment: @LindsayWade Please refrain from using offensive language — it doesn't seem to make sense to use it toward the people who you're trying to get help from, in particular, but please refrain from using it against anyone.

Answer (score 11):

We're not refusing to help you per se, at the same time we don't understand your position on this matter at all.

We don't know who work for and what kind of job you do that requires identifying 127 pieces of animation cels with next to nothing to go on. I'm sure you would feel the same way if some stranger came to your door and asked you to identify 127 pieces of early modern to postmodern European and American art, because they hear you know a thing or two about art.

From your comments it sounds like you don't care at much for Japanese anime or animation in general and that's fine. A job's a job. You don't have to like what you do.

However if you ask for help, it's common courtesy to at least explain to the other party why you're need this work done. Maybe it's for a upcoming exhibit at a gallery or museum, maybe it's from a collection inherited from a relative. Whatever the reason maybe, disclosing your intent will better understand what you're looking for.

The will the scope of the work if a bit excessive, we maybe able to helps you with a portion of it, but we certainly can't do your job for you. If you can tell us what you've tried so far and why that didn't work out, we can point you to the right direction. Not everyone is good at looking for stuff, but at the same time not everyone is willing to do another work for them without knowing why.

If you're under a nondisclosure agreement, then say so, provide what you can and we'll try to help you fill in the blanks. Answering question is about give and take. If all you do is taker, then there won't be anyone left to give you anything.

If you or someone else brought them from a Japanese seller, then there should be at least a receipt or invoice, even if it's in Japanese, there's a chance that there might be some leads as to where they came from. Collectors rarely buy anything without know where it came from. So instead of asking strangers on the internet where there individual cels are from, have you tried getting in contact with the purchaser? That might give you your first lead.

Seeing as you're located in San Antonio, TX area from your profile, have you tried reaching out to auction houses in your area for referral to an appraiser of animation cels? Without a subject matter expert to help you, identifying all those cels will be rather difficult. It can probably be justified to the owner of the collection to get the collection appraised for insurance purposes. Even more so if the intent is to resell them.