# Change the ID request close plaque text to include a link to a meta post for self-help and tips

Tags: discussion, identification-questions

Right now (and this has been going on for a very long time) the text says this:

> **Identification questions** are off-topic, because they tend to attract low-quality and low-effort posts. The community has decided to no longer support these questions. Please refer to [this meta post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/what-wed-like-to-do-about-those-gosh-darn-identification-requests-questions) for additional details.

The link leads to a meta post explaining *why we decided to ban ID requests*. And it's super long and nobody's got time to read it. Maybe it has some links to self-help, but I'm sure 99% of people who clicked it didn't find it. And I don't think anyone cares why we don't want to help them. The text is official and dry. That's bad close plaque text.

I propose this new text instead:

> **Identification questions** are [no longer allowed on this site since April 2016](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/what-wed-like-to-do-about-those-gosh-darn-identification-requests-questions).
>
> But you can [**identify it yourself**](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12345/example-link) with our list of [self-help tips and tricks](https://same.link.as.before/just-because-it%27s-easier-to-catch-users%27-attention-this-way) on how to identify anime, manga and merchandise.

Of course, we'll need to actually compile those links in a convenient user-friendly self-help meta post.

What do you think?

Comment: Related previous discussion: [Let's change the ID request close reason plaque to redirect askers to other sites](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4123/lets-change-the-id-request-close-reason-plaque-to-redirect-askers-to-other-site), and I'm all for improving this close reason.

Comment: As per [my answer](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4290/2516) on the previous discussion, since then I wrote [What identification requests are acceptable here? Otherwise, where else can I possibly get helped with it?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4189) and linked it on the current meta post. Consider this "done".